# django dynamic file serving optimization

Tags: python, django, apache

I am working on a django project that provides an API to generate thumbnails of images, and the basic logic is like the following:

1. when the source image URL comes for the first time, the django would do some sort of image manipulation, and return the thumbnail image
2. when the same image URL comes again, django would simply serve the previous thumbnail image (stored as static media) again.

basically, case 2 happened much often than case 1. Now I used django to serve the images all the time, which I believe is a bad practice.

I wonder if it's possible to do a better way of image serving for case 2? For example, is there some sort of way to ask django to send proxy requests to apache and ask apache to serve the file?

I know I could use HTTP redirect to do that, but that seems to generate too much redirect requests on the client side (one HTML page would contain a lot of links to this API).

thx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest solution of the top of my head would be to use an Apache rewrite rule with a condition.

```
RewriteCond %(REQUEST_URI) ^media
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteRule #Some rewrite rule to redirect from '/media/filename' to '/image_generator/filename'
```

This basically just checks to see whether the file exists in the media directory, and if it doesn't it sends the user to the image generator, which can then generate and save the file to /media where it can be found for the next request.

NB: I've never actually tried this sort of redirection with Django, so it may need some measure of tweaking..

Comment: thanks for the hint, and I checked http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#RewriteCond, however that would require me to pass the full local image path to the URL, is that correct?

Comment: The REQUEST_FILENAME variable should contain the path to the file on your system, as resolved from the URI by Apache. You therefore shouldn't need to pass any local paths through the URI. There are some caveats to this, which are described in the Apache docs you linked to, but I'm pretty sure it should work in this context.

Comment: thanks, I guess that would work, but I might need to change the URL structure though.

Comment: just some updates, I found the following link is extremely useful as well: http://www.simonecarletti.com/blog/2009/01/apache-rewriterule-and-query-string/  eventually I solved the problem by integrating this answer and URL

Answer (score 0):

> For example, is there some sort of way to ask django to send proxy requests to apache and ask apache to serve the file?

You have that exactly backwards.

Read the Django deployment guide.  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/howto/deployment/modwsgi/#serving-files

Apache should be serving **all** static files (images, for example) all the time.  Always.

Django should never, ever serve an image file (or a .css or .js or anything other than .html).

Comment: @SLott, sometimes you want to create on-the-fly resources.  For example, a [1234px by 567px image](http://placehold.it/1234x567).

Comment: @FakeRainBrigand: Correct.  You **must** create a file in the media directory which is then served by Apache in the normal course of handling the response.  You do not want your Django threads wasting time waiting for (slow) trickles of bytes to the client desktop.  You want Apache (and caches) to handle this outside Django.

Comment: yes, I know it's not a good practice. But in the described case, the thumbnail image does not exist until the first call is done, how am I supposed to describe that in the apache then?

Comment: @Walty: You don't "describe it to Apache".  Your Django view function simply creates the file in the media directories *which are already being served by Apache*.  After the HTML page is sent, the browser requests the images, which are sent by Apache.  Not Django.

Answer (score 0):

See later part of this section in documentation:

http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ConfigurationGuidelines#The_Apache_Alias_Directive

Using Alias/AddHandler/mod_rewrite allows Django to overlay static files in filesystem. In other words, static files take precedence.